# How does ZF set theory prevent Russell's Paradox

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

In chapter 1 § 5 of Set theory by Kenneth Kunen. Kunnen explains that a naive attempt for formalizing Axiom of Comprehension would look like $\exists y \forall x (x \in y \leftrightarrow \phi)$.

But the book claim it is incorrect because when we define $\phi$ as $x \notin x$ we can have the following deduction $\forall x (x \in y \leftrightarrow x \notin x)$,And when $x = y$ we get $(y \in y \leftrightarrow y \notin y)$.

So instead the book suggests the correct Axiom to be $\exists y \forall x (x \in y \leftrightarrow x \in z \wedge \phi)$.

But when I tried following the exact same step I ended up with $(y \in y \leftrightarrow y \in z \wedge y \notin y)$.

If $y \in z$ evaluated to *true*, we will end with the exact same predicate as with the naive Axiom of comprehension. I know that Russell's paradox should not work in ZF set theory, but I cannot figure out what is wrong with my reasoning.

Comment: What that proves is that the set $y$ of all $x$ in $z$ that satisfy $x\notin x$ cannot satisfy $y\in z$. But this is not a problem because we never said it had to be an element of $z$. In fact, this proves that for every set $z$, there is a set $y$ that is not an element of $z$. It's not a contradiction or paradox.

Comment: That is: note that you have an undischarged assumption, namely that $y\in z$ evaluates to *true*. The contradiction means that the undischarged assumption is false, hence we conclude that $y\notin z$. In the original argument with unrestricted comprehension, there are no undischarged assumptions, so in that case we have a bona fide contradiction in our theory.

Comment: You mean "comprehension" not "choice" in the last paragraph. As to your question, as @ArturoMagidin's comments imply, you argument leads to the conclusion that  $y \in z$ is false if $y$ is the set $\{x \in z \mid x \not\in x\}$ that the ZF axiom of comprehension asserts to exist for any $z$.

Comment: Kunen requires that $\phi$ is a formula *without $y$ free*, so it can mention $x$, $z$ or other parameters, but not $y$. I think the purpose is exactly to avoid self-reference.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Does that mean that since we need (y∈y↔y∈z∧y∉y) to be true we just assume that y∈z must always be false? I cannot intuit how can we be sure that this is the case except for that it is only way for the proof to hold. It feels to be a strange kind of proof by contradiction.

Comment: No, we do not just "assume $y\in z$ is always false". We *conclude* that for $y=\{x\in z\mid x\notin x\}$, it must be the case that $y\notin z$. Because for that $y$, $y\in z$ leads to $(y\in y)\wedge(y\notin y)$. It is not just not a "strange kind" of proof by contradiction, it is a *classic* proof by contradiction: for that particular $y$, $y\in z$ leads to a contradiction, hence for that $y$, it follows that $y\notin z$.

Comment: The axiom tells us that $y \in z$ is false. This isn't an "assumption": think of the axiom as giving us a way of constructing new sets from old: for each formula $\phi$ and set $z$ you get the set that you can write as $y = \{x \in z \mid \phi(x)\}$ whose defining property is $\forall x(x \in y \leftrightarrow x \in z \land \phi(x))$. Any logical consequence of that property holds of $y$, in particular, the property that $y \not \in z$, if $\phi(x)$ is $x \not\in x$..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a flaw in my my proof and when I tried to write the proof formally I think I was able to see why the paradox does not hold.

The proof is Gentzen style (which the book does not use) and it was the only way I was able to follow.

The Full Axiom of Comprehension says that: For each formula $\phi$ with free variables among $x, y, z, w_1, ..., w_n$
$$
\forall z \forall w_1, ..., w_n\exists y \forall x (x\in y \leftrightarrow x \in z \wedge \phi)
$$

We assume $\phi$ is $x \notin x$ so we no longer need $w_1,....w_n$

The proof will look like following:

$$
\dfrac
{
\dfrac{
\dfrac{
\dfrac{
\dfrac{
\dfrac{}{z, x, x \in z \vdash x \in z \wedge x \notin x}\text{*}
}
{z, x \vdash (x\in z \rightarrow x \in z \wedge x \notin x)}
~~~~~~~
\dfrac{
\dfrac{}{z, x, x \in z, x \notin x \vdash x \in z}(assumptions)}
{z, x \vdash x \in z \wedge x \notin x \rightarrow x \in z} (\text{introuce the hypothesis})
}{
z, x \vdash x\in z \leftrightarrow x \in z \wedge x \notin x
}(\text{split equivalence})}{z \vdash \forall x (x\in z \leftrightarrow x \in z \wedge x \notin x)} ( \text{introduce } x)
}
{z \vdash \exists y \forall x (x\in y \leftrightarrow x \in z \wedge x \notin x)} (\text{exists }z)
}
{\vdash\forall z \exists y \forall x (x\in y \leftrightarrow x \in z \wedge x \notin x) } (\text{introduce } z)
$$

The continuation of proof of `*` is:

1- Proving that $z, x, x \in z \vdash x \in z$ which is trivial by assumptions.

2- Proving that $z, x, x \in z \vdash x \notin x$. which is the same as
$z, x, x \in z, x \in x \vdash false$. I struggled there for a bit but I learned that this is a direct consequence from Foundational Axiom which will be discussed later in chapter 3.